# Store the number of matches in VimScript function?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression

Is there any way to store the number of matches in a variable in a VIMScript function?

For instance I'm using:

```
%s/,//gn
```

Comment: You can't. Could you describe what you are trying to do instead of your failed attempts?

Comment: @romainl I'm trying to convert a line with commas to a vertical list without so many steps;  I figured I'd throw it into a vimscript.  At the moment I do a search for commas, record a macro that moves to the next match, moves over one character to the right for the comma, presses enter, and then delete.  I can run the macro over and over again, but I have to count the number of matches first, so I know how many times to run the macro.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple substitution? Something like `:s/,/,\r/g`?

Comment: @romainl Good point.  Too much switching between Windows and Linux I guess.

Comment: I ended up using `%s/,\W*/,\r/g` because of white space.

Comment: The regex for white spaces is `\s`, `\_s` if you want to match newlines as well.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Windows or Linux.  Vim always uses `\r` to represent EOL in the replacement (and `\n` in the search) regardless of what line ending is in effect for the buffer.  The type of line ending is controlled by the `'fileformat'` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way that doesn't move the cursor nor requires `:exe`, but uses other tricks. Here I count by using a function that modifies and returns something (if `+=` was an expression like in C, it would have been simpler)

```
command! -nargs=1 -range Count call s:Count2(<f-args>, <line1>,<line2>)

" Not using the usual :function-range to avoid moving the cursor
function! s:Count2(param, firstl, lastl) abort
  let s:c = []
  call map(getline(a:firstl, a:lastl), { k,v -> substitute(v, 'line', '\=add(s:c, v)[-1]', 'g')})
  echo len(s:c)
endfunction
```

Comment: You might want `let l:c`, no reason to leak it to the script namespace.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble When I've tested the function, I've tried with local variables, but it failed -- with Vim 8.1-1655. I had to use a more global scope. It looks like a defect though because the _old_ syntax works: `call map(getline(a:firstl, a:lastl), "substitute(v:val, 'line', '\\=add(l:c, v:val)[-1]', 'g')")`, and I don't even need to add this noisy `l:` prefix.

Comment: Thats bizarre...

Answer (score 9):

I know that @romainl debugged the question as a XY problem in the comments but I guess it still could be useful to some people, so here is a solution. *(It is deeply inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23724875/4194289))*

You can use this function (to add to your `.vimrc` or to your script):

```
function! Count( word )
  redir => cnt
    silent exe '%s/' . a:word . '//gn'
  redir END

  let res = strpart(cnt, 0, stridx(cnt, " "))
  return res
endfunction
```

You can call the function like this: `:call Count("pattern")`.

For example in this file:

```
a,bc
akj,dh
jlkdfa,
oiua ,lkj
oiua, lkj
oiua , lkj
i,
```

With `:echo Count(",")` you'll get `7`.

Comment: Well in this context Romainl's suggestion wasn't awful because it was really the best solution for OP's context. It's still nice if the answer was helpful for you! :)

Comment: This actually returns a `^@` in-front of the result, so can't really be used. _e.g._ `echo Count("word") + 1` will always return 1.  See my amended answer below.

Answer (score 2):

**Warning**: The accepted answer does not return a number or number-like object. This does.

```
function! Count( word )
  redir => cnt
    silent exe '%s/' . a:word . '//n'
  redir END
  return matchstr( cnt, '\d\+' )
endfunction
```

With the same instructions as the accepted answer, except you can actually perform further calculations with the result, *e.g.:*

```
echo Count("word") + 2
```

or something superbly more complex:

```
function! MyMatch()
  let results = ingo#text#frompattern#Get(1, '$', 'j\w\{1,5\} \zs\(loc\|lab\)_\w\+\ze', '', '', '1')
  let counter=1
  for result in results
    if Count(result) != 2
      execute '%s/' . result . '/label' . counter . '/g'
      let counter+=1
    endif
  endfor
endfun
```

Comment: It's cool to see an answer improved 3 years after it was posted :) Well done!

Comment: @statox my stackexchange golden rule: "If you can't copy the solution from someone else's hard work, then submit your own hard work where possible."  a.k.a. "Nobody likes a leech."

Answer (score 1):

If you have a new enough version of vim which suport [:h execute()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#execute%28%29) , you can get count like this:

```
function! GetCount(pattern)
  let l:cnt = 0
  silent exe '%s/' . a:pattern . '/\=execute(''let l:cnt += 1'')/gn'
  return l:cnt
endfunction
```

In fact you can get all the matches and put them in a list:

```
function! GetMatches(pattern)
  let l:matches = []
  silent exe '%s/' . a:pattern .
        \ '/\=execute(''let l:matches += [submatch(0)]'')/gn'
  return l:matches
endfunction
```

**update**

As [Christian Brabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt) pointed out, you can use [:h add()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#add%28%29) , it's simpler :

```
function! GetMatches(pattern)
  let l:matches = []
  silent exe '%s/' . a:pattern . '/\=add(l:matches, submatch(0))/gn'
  return l:matches
endfunction
```

Comment: simpler: `\=add(matches, submatch(0))/gn`, don't need `execute()` for that.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks, updated.