# How to yank count of matches of a pattern to a register?

Tags: vimscript, search, counting

```
%s///n
```

show number of matching pattern like `102 matches on 102 lines.`

How to copy this output to a register?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but a very related question [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6975/1841)

Comment: take a look at this [plugin](https://github.com/google/vim-searchindex), it may already contain what you want

Answer (score 4):

```
:redir @a | %s///n | redir END
```

An alternative is

```
:let @a=execute('%s///n')
```

If `%s///n` is the last command, you can type:

```
:let @a=execute('<Ctrl-r>:')
```

or if you want to paste it immediately into the document, switch to insert mode and type

```
<Ctrl-r>=execute('<Ctrl-r>:')
```

**Relevant Links**

- [`:h :redir`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Aredir)
- [`:h execute()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#execute%28%29)
- Gist `:Redir` https://gist.github.com/intuited/362802 `:R %s///n @a`
- https://github.com/mhinz/vim-galore#redir-and-execute
- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Capture_ex_command_output
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453211/how-do-i-capture-the-output-of-a-vim-command-in-a-register-without-the-newlines

Comment: Would `:let @a=execute(@:)` work as well?

Comment: Should work as well. However, you have no immediate feedback what in `@:` is. Some people develop the habit of pressing `:w` without thinking about it and 'mess up' the register `@:`. Pressing `<C-r>:` tells you immediately what you gonna execute.