# How can I store the number of regex matches in a variable?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, variables

In Vim Script, I want to check for the amount of matches from a regular expression (`/\%^\n*`) and store the amount of matches in a variable. I this possible?

Comment: Does this solve your problem: [Store the number of matches in VimScript function](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20666/16280)?

Comment: Looking at your regex I believe it will only match once. Maybe you would like to get the length of the matching string?

Comment: You are right, it does only match once. What I actually intend to do is store the amount of leading blank lines (not including lines with only whitespace) into a variable.

Comment: @kadekai the solutions posted there work with characters, but they do not seem to work with regular expressions (it returns the incorrect amount).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the count of matches with `:h searchcount()`. It returns a dictionary with the following values:

```
key           type            meaning ~
current       |Number|        current position of match;
                              0 if the cursor position is
                              before the first match
exact_match   |Boolean|       1 if "current" is matched on
                              "pos", otherwise 0
total         |Number|        total count of matches found
incomplete    |Number|        0: search was fully completed
                              1: recomputing was timed out
                              2: max count exceeded
```

Since we only need the total match count, we can discard all values except `total` from the returned dictionary.

And as input `searchcount` takes a dictionary as its `{options}` parameter, which accepts a pattern. We can utilize this input parameter.

```
:let var = searchcount(#{pattern: '^\n'}).total
:echo var
```

NOTE: The hash character (#) before the dictionary argument of `searchcount` is a way to circumvent the requirement of quoting the dictionary keys; see `:h literal-Dict`.